# can not reading dot env value in axios. If importing dotenv to configure it raises dotenv is undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, node-modules, dotenv

I am using axios.create to create get request. When I am using process.env.api_key, it gives an undefined value. When I am importing dotenv and configuring it it says dotenv is not found. Here are some pics.

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import dotenv from 'dotenv'
    dotenv.config()


    export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://twitch-game-popularity.p.rapidapi.com/",
    headers:{
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.RAPID_API_KEY,
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': process.env.RAPID_API_HOST
    }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using create-react-app, all your variables in .env should be called with prefix REACT_APP_ , so in your case it would be REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY.

And I'm not sure what is this for

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

I haven't done it before. All your variables from .env should be accessible via process.env without any imports